# Dwarf Fortress Animal Segregation

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I get my animals to not congregate at the same place my dwarfs do?

Comment: They usually gather in the meeting hall.  What do you want them to do?

Comment: @C. Ross I want them to gather in a barnyard type place.

Comment: @Mana, is Dwarf Fortress only available for PC (or is this question only for the PC version)?

Comment: Dwarf Fortress is only for PC. I'm debating which one of http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi-p 's answers should end up being the standard across the site for tagging. I agree more with the second answer (currently the one with four votes), so I started tagging games for only one platform with that platform...but then I realized people might not like having a bunch of dwarf fortress questions right at the top of the site, so I stopped. <.<;;

Comment: @Mana I'm all for having the front page covered with DF :), but where in the world do you get the idea it's PC only?  Or are you including all the operating systems (Windows, Linux, Mac) under PC?

Comment: Oh, yeah! Sorry about that, I included all the operating systems under PC. x_x I forgot that the term means a computer running Windows. :<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you want with a "barnyard" would be with a [pit](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Activity_zone#Pit.2FPond) and a non-pet passable [door](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Door) (marks as `keep tightly closed`).

To create the pit you can use the channel command, which will leave an area edged with ramps, so your dwarves can get in and out.

Comment: @C. Ross how do I get the animals into the pit?

Comment: @antony View the pit information with `i`,`P` and assign the animals.

Comment: Do you have to care for them differently if you build a pit? For instance, do you have to make sure some Dwarf is throwing food into the pit on a regular basis?

Answer (score 4):

Just make a bunch of ropes and chains and tie them up. They breed via spores, as long as they're not caged they can be chained at opposite ends of the map and still reproduce. Your FPS will thank you.

Comment: Definitely a better solution for FPS, but not exactly a "barnyard".

Comment: +1 good information, but I like the pit suggestion better: little less work.

Comment: really? *"They breed via spores"* I can't imagine animals like plants?

Comment: @Fennekin euphemism. They reproduce magically as long as a mating partner is on the map somewhere, anywhere, even if totally separated by closed walls.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to build cages(b to build then j for cage) and assign the animals to the cages(query the built cage and assign).  A built cage can have any number of tame animals stuffed into it.  Newborn animals will appear outside the cages, so you may have to occasionally assign the new animals to the cage as they show up.  If you're concerned about FPS cages should be pretty good for that, caged animals won't pathfind at all.

Comment: Actually, newborns are born inside the cage with their mothers: http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Captured_creatures